# sql - How to implement an object that has a dynamically varying number of relationships?

Tags: sql, database-design

Suppose I'm building a website that has users who can create "rooms" and add others to them. How would the rooms table keep track of its members without making a new table per room?

Comment: Three tables: One table for rooms. One table for users. One table containing roomid's and userid (to link them)

Comment: CREATE TABLE member_room
(member member_type NOT NULL REFERENCES member (member),
room  room_type NOT NULL REFERENCES room (room),
PRIMARY KEY (member,room));

Comment: Time to read a published academic textbook on information modelling, the relational model & DB design. (Manuals for languages & tools to record & use designs are not textbooks on doing information modeling & database design.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have two tables, one for rooms and one for members.  They would be connected through foreign key relationships:

```
create table rooms (
    room_id int primary key,  -- auto-increment, serial, identity . . .
    . . .
);

create table room_users (
    room_user_id int primary key,   -- auto-increment, serial, identity . . .
    room_id int references rooms(room_id),
    user_id int references users(user_id)
);
```